# Undefined index on form submit

Tags: php, html, forms, form-submit

I write a selection of ids (e.g. "3,4,31") in a disabled `textarea` (works fine so far) and want to submit that via GET.
I don't understand why I keep getting an undefined index error with the following code:

```
<form action="slider/Jssor/image-gallery.source.php" method="get"><br>
  <textarea name="selection" id="result" disabled></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Jssor Imgage Gallery">
</form>
```

`image-gallery.source.php` throws the undefined index error when calling:

```
<?php
  echo $_GET["selection"];
?>
```

The link to the new page works fine so I assume it can't be because of the path in the action attribute!? 
I don't see the Ids transported in the URL (?selection=3,4,31), so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: how do you submit the form to the `PHP` page? Is there a submit button in your form?

Comment: Have you considered using `readonly` instead of `disabled`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `textarea` is not being sent with the form because it's marked as `disabled`. You should mark it as `readonly` if you want it to be sent.

As is stated in http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp:

> Tip: Disabled  elements in a form will not be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 <textarea name="selection" id="result" disabled></textarea>
```

to

```
<textarea name="selection" id="result" readonly></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
   <textarea name="selection" id="result" disabled></textarea>
```

With

```
 <textarea name="selection" id="result" readonly></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have progressed after passing -d. GET works fine and it can identify the submitted value however in case of POST it does not work.